# Dynamically populate variable number of GUI prefabs in vertical scroll view

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to set up a vertically scrollable view containing a dynamic number of prefab panels (to scroll through) each containing dynamically populated `Text` objects.

To achieve this I created `ScrollRect` whose content is a panel (let's call it `contentPanel`) which will contain the variable number of prefabs. This panel is given a vertical `Grid Layout Group` to keep things lined up properly.

When I duplicate the prefabs I am able to scroll through the duplicates as intended. However, when I programmatically instantiate new prefabs and set the parent to `contentPanel` all of the scrollable content disappears.

Here is the code where I instantiate a prefab:

```
    GameObject newAddedPanel = (GameObject) Instantiate(addedPanel);
    newAddedPanel.transform.SetParent(contentPanel.transform);
    if(newAddedPanel != null)
    {
        prefabScript script = newAddedPanel.GetComponent<prefabScript>();
        if(script != null)
        {
            script.populatePanel("text1", "text2");
        }
    }
```

Here `addedPanel` is a reference to the prefab, `prefabScript` is a script which the prefab has attached to it, and `populatePanel()` is one of the methods of the script.

Based on what I've read at [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html), I should not need to do anything further to handle the prefabs' positions since

> If the UI Element is a child of a Layout Group it will be automatically positioned and the positioning step can be skipped

Is there another step I must take to get things working?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Adding screenshots of the scrollable window:[image]

The panel containing the text boxes with values "val11", "vall12" is the first prefab, and the one below is the second, etc. I put 4 on within the inspector just to confirm that scrolling works, which it does.

When new values are entered in the input fields above and the "Add" button is pushed, a new prefab is instantiated and its parent is set to the same parent as the other prefabs. However, the new prefab does not show up when scrolling.

Hope that makes things more clear!

Comment: Set  the newAddedPanel.transform.localposition to vector3.zero after you set their parent, and check scale is ok. You need to control too z index of visualization

Comment: Pass`false` to the `SetParent` function. `newAddedPanel.transform.SetParent(contentPanel.transform,false);`

Comment: Thanks @Programmer. This prevents the panel from disappearing, but the prefab still does not appear. I've also checked the local scale and it is the identity (same as prefab). Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the code that instantiates the prefab? I don't think that's in your question.

Comment: The first line of code is the instantiation of the prefab.

Comment: I thought that's the panel. Sorry, what's happening now? Any screenshot?

Comment: Still same behaviour (i.e. instantiated prefab does not appear). I added a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @Programmer, can we remove the duplicate tag on the question, given that the solution at the linked question does not solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry for that. I was not even notified in your last comment. Don't know why. I have removed the duplicate.